# Displaying different widget types in Recycleview Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I was wondering if it possible to display different widget types in kivy recycleview, I have it displaying textboxes which is great but would it be possible to display Images in the same recycle view or do I have to create another recycleview on top on my existing one, this is my code and current app snapshot, my current understanding is that you can only have one viewclass in recycle view mine is a text input so how would one add another view class to the same recyclerview.

current screen
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8JpE.jpg

main.kv

```
   SelectableReportTextbox:



    size_hint:  None,None
    text_size : self.text_size
    size_hint_y: None
    font_size: self.height*0.2
    foreground_color: [1, 1, 1, 1]
    readonly: True
    background_color: (0.1, 0.3, 0.7, 0.7)
    padding_x: [30,30]
    font_name: 'C:\kivy_venv\Graphics\GIL_____.TTF'
    border: [50,50,50,50]







  ScreenTwo:
  




    canvas.before:


            Rectangle:
                    size:self.size           #100, 100
                    pos: self.pos
                    source: "C:\kivy_venv\Graphics\Jetfire back.png"


    RecycleView:

            do_scroll: True, True
            bar_width: 6
            size_hint: (None, None)
            id: scrlv
            size: (500, 500)
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .75, 'center_y': .64}
            scroll_y: 0
            multiline:True




            ProjectRV:

                    viewclass: 'SelectableReportTextbox'        # defines the viewtype for the data items.
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
                    scroll_wheel_distance: dp(114)
                    key_size: "height"

                    padding:1, 1
                    space_x: self.size[0]/3
                    id: rv
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.32, 'center_y': 0.525}
                    bar_width: dp(25)
                    bar_color: (0.7, 0.1, 0.3, 0.7)
                    bar_inactive_color: (0.1, 0.1, 0.1 , 1)
                    scroll_y : 0





                    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:


                            data : []
                            spacing : '5'
                            default_size_hint: 1, None
                            size_hint_y: None
                            height: self.minimum_height
                            multiselect: True
                            touch_multiselect: True
                            orientation: 'vertical'




                            SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:

                                    data : []
                                    color:(0, 0.7, 0.4, 0.4)
                                    spacing : '5'
                                    default_size_hint: 1, None
                                    size_hint_y: None
                                    height: self.minimum_height
                                    multiselect: True
                                    touch_multiselect: True
                                    orientation: 'vertical'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own `viewclass` that displays whatever you want. Your `viewclass` must have `Properties` that correspond to the keys in the `data` of the `RecycleView`.

Here is a simple example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView


class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # set up the data
        self.data = [
            {'text': 'Some Text', 'image': 'dots.png'},
            {'text': 'more text', 'image': 'tester.png'}
            ]

kv = '''
<MyViewClass@BoxLayout>:
    # define the properties that appear in the data
    text: ''
    image: ''
    
    # define how the data is displayed
    Image:
        source: root.image
    Label:
        text: root.text
RV:
    viewclass: 'MyViewClass'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        padding: 10, 0, 10, 0
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        default_size: None, 40
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: 3
'''

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

TestApp().run()
```

Comment: thanks John you are always so helpful your example is great